# Block a certain element in web browser Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I a wondering if and how you would be able to block a certain element in the webbrowser.

For example there is a certain element on a website:

```
<div class="btn" id="button" value="ClickMe"/>
```

Will you be able to block or hide that specific element in the webbrowser?

There might be a certain ad, iframe or whatever its called that might just be in the way?

Thanks for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: u want to remove this before loading page on webbrowser or what ??

Comment: try my updated answer ad let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

double click on webbrowser1 designer you should be in `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` add this line

'selector by division id

```
webbrowser1.Document.getElementById("button").innerHtml = ""
```

'selector spesific element with spesific attribute

```
<input id="_authentication_token" name="_authentication_token" type="hidden" value="11740686"/>

dim mycol as htmlElementCollection = webbrowser1.document.getElementBytagname("input")

for each ele as Htmlelement in mycol  

if (ele.getAttribute("value").tostring = "11740686") then ele.innerHtml = "" 

next
```

**for your exemple :**

```
<div class="btn" id="button" value="ClickMe"/>

dim mycol as htmlElementCollection = webbrowser1.document.getElementBytagname("div")

for each ele as Htmlelement in mycol  

if (ele.getAttribute("value").tostring = "ClickMe" and ele.getAttribute("id").tostring = "button" ) then ele.innerHtml = "" 

next
```

Comment: Yeah I'd like to remove an element before it loads in the webpage so its basically hidden or blocked from view

Comment: @TylerD. you should not wrong on the selector to perform best results